# JVM Memory Segments and JIT Compiler

Tags: jvm, jit

I know this is JVM dependent and every virtual machine would choose to implement it a little bit different yet I want to understand the overall concept.

It has been said that for the Memory Segments that the JVM uses to execute a Java program

1. Java Stacks
2. Heap
3. Method Area
4. PC Registers
5. Native Method Stacks

are not necessarily implemented with contiguous memory and may be all actually allocated on some heap memory provided from the OS, this leads me to my question.

- JVM's that fully use the JIT mechanism and compiles bytecode methods
  into native machinecode methods store these methods somewhere, where
  would that be? the execution engine ( that is usually written in C /
  C++ ) would have to invoke these JIT compiled functions, yet the kernel shouldn't allow a program to execute code saved on the  stack / heap / static memory segment, how could the JVM overcome this?
- Another question I have is regarding the Java stacks, when a method ( after JIT compilation ) is executed within the processor it's local variables should be saved within the Java stacks, yet again the Java stacks may be implemented with a non-contiguous memory and perhaps even just some stack data structure allocated on the heap acting as a stack, how and where do the local variables of a method being executed get saved? the kernel shouldn't allow a program to treat a heap allocated memory as a process stack, how does JVM overcome this difficuly as well?

Again, I want to emphasis that I'm asking for an overall concept, I know each JVM would choose to implement this a little bit different...

Answer (score 0):

> JVM's that fully use the JIT mechanism and compiles bytecode methods into native machinecode methods store these methods somewhere, where would that be?

It is stored in the "Perm Gen" in Java <= 7 and "meta space" in Java 8.  This is another native memory region.

> the execution engine ( that is usually written in C / C++ ) would have to invoke these JIT compiled functions, yet the kernel shouldn't allow a program to execute code saved on the stack / heap / static memory segment, how could the JVM overcome this?

The memory region is both writable and executable, though I don't know exactly which system call is required to implement this.

> Another question I have is regarding the Java stacks, when a method ( after JIT compilation )

Initially the code is not compiled but it uses the stack in the same way.

> is executed within the processor it's local variables should be saved within the Java stacks, yet again the Java stacks may be implemented with a non-contiguous memory

There is a stack per thread which is continuous.

> and perhaps even just some stack data structure allocated on the heap acting as a stack, how and where do the local variables of a method being executed get saved?

On the thread stack.

> the kernel shouldn't allow a program to treat a heap allocated memory as a process stack, how does JVM overcome this difficuly as well?

It doesn't do this.

Comment: The stack per thread is the java stack which Im refering to, also what does that mean it is stored within native memory, howcome? It should be stored within either the stack / heap how does it end up executing it. Also many times a jvm would implement it's own stacks per thread memory using heap memory, which again leads me to my original question, how does it treat a stack structure as a native stack..... This doesnt exactly answer my question... Could you please expand more regarding the native memory segment? Thank you eitherway